# Positivity of a Sine transform of a positive function

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Consider a function $f(t)$ with $f(t>0)>0$ and $f(-t)=-f(t)$. Can I make any statement about the positivity of the Sine transform
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(\omega t) f(t) \mathrm{d}t$$
of such a function? I guess that $\hat{f}(\omega>0)>0$, but I am not sure why.

**Edit:** Apparently, my guess was wrong. However, I would still be interested, if there exist additional conditions for $f(t)$, which lead to $\hat{f}(\omega>0)>0$. So far, I have only found the condition $f''(t)>0$ for all $t>0$, which has been proven in *E. Tuck, Bull. Austral. Math Soc. Vol. 74 (2006), p. 133*.

*Background:* In statistical physics, there emerge kernels $f(t)$ with the above-mentioned properties. Conservation of energy implies that $\hat{f}(\omega>0)>0$ must hold true.

Comment: What's the relevance of considering $f(-t)$ when the integral is one-sided ?

Comment: Your are of course correct: there is no direct consequence for the integral as shown here. However, the given symmetry allows for a direct inversion of the Sine transform so that $f \sim \int \sin(\omega t) \hat{f}(\omega)$. Moreover, it also allows to directly express the Sine transform as a Fourier transform, which might simplify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider for instance $f(t)=t\,|t|\,e^{-|t|}$. Then
$$
\hat f(\omega)=\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-t}\sin(\omega\,t)\,dt=\frac{2\,\omega\left(3-\omega^2\right)}{\left(\omega^2+1\right)^3}
$$
is $<0$ for $\omega>\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample! I guess that therefore there must be additional constraints to $f(t)$ in physics. Small remark: your example function should read $f(t) = t |t| e^{-|t|}$ to be formally uneven.